# Can you choose a thread from a thread pool to execute (boost)

Tags: boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

Here is some code i have atm.

```
int main()
{

   boost::thread_group threads; // Thread Pool

   // Here we create threads and kick them off by passing 
   // the address of the function to call
   for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
       threads.create_thread(&SendDataToFile);

   threads.join_all();

   system("PAUSE");

}

void SendDataToFile()
{
   // The lock guard will make sure only one thread (client)
   // will access this application at once
   boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(io_mutex);
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       cout << "Writing" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << endl;
}
```

At the moment im just using cout instead of writing to file.

Is it possible to actually choose a thread to carry out an operation before another thread. So i have a file i want to write to, 4 threads want to access that file at the same time, is it possible for me to say ok thread 2 you go first. ? in BOOST

can the fstream be used like cout? when i did write to a file the output was not messy (without a mutex)? but when i print to the console without a mutex it is messy as you would expect.

Comment: Link may be helpful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29

Comment: @user2202911 is there any boost examples on this?

Comment: I am unaware of any - sorry.

Comment: Can you be more specific? If you want to get the index of the child thread in `SendDataToFile()` function, you can use `boost::bind()`. If you want to start one child thread first, just start the thread first separately and wait until the thread joins. (*)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of equivalent ways you could do this using some combination of global variables protected by atomic updates, a mutex, semaphore, condition variable, etc.  The way that seems to me to most directly communicate what you're trying to do is to have your threads wait on a [ticket lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_lock) where instead of their ticket number representing the order that they arrived at the lock, it's chosen to be the order in which the threads were created.  You could combine that idea with the [Boost spinlock example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.example_spinlock) for a simple and probably performant implementation.